# Convert string to dictionary in bash

Tags: bash

How do I convert a string to bash dictionary? I get the string in the following format.

```
{ foo1 = [ "User1", "User2" ] bar1 = [ "User3", "User4" ] }
{ foo2 = [ "User5", "User6" ] }
{ foo3 = ["User7", "User8"] , bar2 = [ "User9", "User10", "User 11" ], moo = ["User12"] }
```

I have to convert to the following format in bash dictionary.

```
`( ["foo1"]= ("User1,User2") , ["bar1"]= ( "User3,User4" ))`
`( ["foo2"]=( "User5,User6" ) )`
`( ["foo3"]=("User7"), ["bar2"] = ( "User9,User10,User 11" ), ["moo"] = 
("User12"))`
```

Comment: Bash associative arrays can only hold scalar values, no arrays, so what you want doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: ( ["foo1"]= ("User1 , User2") , ["bar1"]= ( "User3 , User4" ))
    ( ["foo2"]=( "User5 , User6" ) )
    ( ["foo3"]=("User7"), ["bar2"] = ( "User9 , User10 , User 11" ), ["moo"] = 
    ("User12")). Is it possible this way?

Comment: You'd want the value of key `foo1` to be the string `User1, User2`, do I understand that right?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Comment: The first question you should always ask yourself when faced with parsing an arbitrary string into (what passes for) a data structure in `bash` is "What is generating this string, and can I change it into something more `bash`-friendly?" Put bluntly, though, shell scripts really aren't supposed to be dealing with data; they are for running other programs that deal with data.

Comment: I am getting this data from icinga. And no i cannot make it more bash friendly.

Comment: Since you haven't received an answer yet, I'd say it's okay to [edit] your question and amend what you said in your comment (the alternative format you pointed out). Make sure you're precise: do you really want `User1, User2` with an extra space, or would `User1,User2` work as well? The first is considerably more annoying to work with.

Comment: User1,User2 can also work.

Comment: I am trying to send the users email.

Comment: This question seems to be "how do i parse complex data in bash" - which is arguably "doing it wrong". So I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score -2):

Bash is not the right tool for parsing complex data. Look into changing the source of the input to be more shell-friendly instead or use a tool like `jq` to deal with JSON data - if that is the format of the original data.